# How to compare current date with a date in database

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, momentjs

How can I make a selection comparing only the current date with the date saved in the DB in this format: DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.
This is the table model, I'm using Nodejs and sequelize to create the table.

```
const User = connection.define("users", {
    id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    login: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        get() {
            return moment(this.getDataValue('createdAt')).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
        }
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        get() {
            return moment(this.getDataValue('updatedAt')).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
        }
    }
})
```

I need to make a selection where updatedAt equals current date.

Comment: Note that Moment.js is deprecated and no longer receiving new features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I created date in this format:

```
var date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

And inside the model in the column `createdAt`, I defined it as DATEONLY.